# JPA Creating entity class from database

Tags: sql, eclipse, jpa, entity

I'm trying to create classes using "JPA Entities from Tables". I am connected to a database that has a structure described by SQL below or described in this image[image]
It only creates 4 classes and 2 doesn't [image]
What is wrong in my database?

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Baza danych: `pawww8`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Struktura tabeli dla tabeli `category`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `category` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_polish_ci;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Struktura tabeli dla tabeli `customer`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customer` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL,
  `city_region` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL,
  `cc_number` varchar(19) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_polish_ci;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Struktura tabeli dla tabeli `customer_order`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customer_order` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `amount` decimal(6,2) NOT NULL,
  `date_created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `confirmation_number` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `customer_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_polish_ci;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Struktura tabeli dla tabeli `customer_order_has_product`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customer_order_has_product` (
  `customer_order_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `quantity` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_polish_ci;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Struktura tabeli dla tabeli `product`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,
  `description` tinytext COLLATE utf8_polish_ci,
  `last_update` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `category_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_polish_ci;

--
-- Indeksy dla zrzutów tabel
--

--
-- Indexes for table `category`
--
ALTER TABLE `category`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Indexes for table `customer`
--
ALTER TABLE `customer`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Indexes for table `customer_order`
--
ALTER TABLE `customer_order`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `customer_id` (`customer_id`);

--
-- Indexes for table `customer_order_has_product`
--
ALTER TABLE `customer_order_has_product`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`customer_order_id`,`product_id`),
  ADD KEY `customer_order_id` (`customer_order_id`),
  ADD KEY `product_id` (`product_id`);

--
-- Indexes for table `product`
--
ALTER TABLE `product`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `category_id` (`category_id`),
  ADD KEY `category_id_2` (`category_id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT dla tabeli `category`
--
ALTER TABLE `category`
  MODIFY `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT dla tabeli `customer`
--
ALTER TABLE `customer`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT dla tabeli `customer_order`
--
ALTER TABLE `customer_order`
  MODIFY `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
--
-- Ograniczenia dla zrzutów tabel
--

--
-- Ograniczenia dla tabeli `customer_order`
--
ALTER TABLE `customer_order`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `customer_order_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customer` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `customer_order_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `customer_order_has_product` (`customer_order_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Ograniczenia dla tabeli `product`
--
ALTER TABLE `product`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `product_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `category` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `product_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `customer_order_has_product` (`product_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: Which classes you say is missing or not generated?

Comment: I'm sure you are using some IDE, because that "JPA Entities from Tables" appears somewhere. So tag your question as that. And JPA does not provide such a feature ... it is a feature of the IDE

Comment: He classes taht it doesnt are underlined in red on he screen. They are product and customer order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote my database and it **does create** proper classes. Code below. But i have completely no idea why it refused to create models for the previous one

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Baza danych: `testowa`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Struktura tabeli dla tabeli `category`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `category` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_polish_ci;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Struktura tabeli dla tabeli `customer`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customer` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL,
  `city_region` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL,
  `cc_number` varchar(19) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_polish_ci;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Struktura tabeli dla tabeli `customer_order`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customer_order` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `amount` decimal(6,2) NOT NULL,
  `date_created` date NOT NULL,
  `confirmation_number` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `customer_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_polish_ci;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Struktura tabeli dla tabeli `customer_order_has_product`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customer_order_has_product` (
  `customer_order_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `quantity` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_polish_ci;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Struktura tabeli dla tabeli `product`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,
  `description` tinytext COLLATE utf8_polish_ci,
  `last_update` date NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_polish_ci;

--
-- Indeksy dla zrzutów tabel
--

--
-- Indexes for table `category`
--
ALTER TABLE `category`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Indexes for table `customer`
--
ALTER TABLE `customer`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Indexes for table `customer_order`
--
ALTER TABLE `customer_order`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `customer_id` (`customer_id`);

--
-- Indexes for table `customer_order_has_product`
--
ALTER TABLE `customer_order_has_product`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`customer_order_id`,`product_id`),
  ADD KEY `product_id` (`product_id`);

--
-- Indexes for table `product`
--
ALTER TABLE `product`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `category_id` (`category_id`);

--
-- Ograniczenia dla zrzutów tabel
--

--
-- Ograniczenia dla tabeli `customer_order`
--
ALTER TABLE `customer_order`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `customer_order_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `category` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Ograniczenia dla tabeli `customer_order_has_product`
--
ALTER TABLE `customer_order_has_product`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `customer_order_has_product_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `product` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `customer_order_has_product_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_order_id`) REFERENCES `customer_order` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Ograniczenia dla tabeli `product`
--
ALTER TABLE `product`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `product_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `customer` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```